# How to Yii enable ajaxLink on pager of CListView?

Tags: ajax, pagination, yii

When use Yii, I see pagination on CGridView within ajaxUpdate. That is very usefully. Now, I need merge it into CListView. But i don't know what is setting for ajaxUpdate.

Here is `controller code`:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Match',array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition' => 'group_id = :groupId',
        'params'    => array(':groupId'=>$groupId),
        'order'=>'date DESC',
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>3,
    ),
));
$this->renderPartial($view = "_matchsOfGroup", array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
));
```

Here is my `view code` **_matchsOfGroup**:

```
<div class="lobbyMain">
    <?php
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
            'template'=>'{items}{pager}',
            'itemView'=>'_match',
            'pager'=>array(
                'header'        => '',
                'maxButtonCount'=> '3',                    
            ),            
        ));
    ?>
</div>
```

and `_match` partial

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>Player</th>
    <th>stack</th>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach($data->matchResults as $result) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data->date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result->user->username; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result->total_stack; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

How to config  'pager'=>array() in `zii.widgets.CListView` to use ajax link request

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->renderPartial($view = "_matchsOfGroup", array(
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
```

change to

```
 $this->renderPartial($view = "_matchsOfGroup", array(
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider),false, true);
```

Comment: Oh, It's still doesn't work. Because configuration 'pager'=>array(...) is generate gereral links `<a href="index.php?r=controller/Get_Data_Link&page=3">next</a>`. I hope it can generate `ajaxLinks` to send ajax request.

Comment: The code i wrote earlier makes Yii to generate js code requiared for enabling ajax pagination. Im not sure but it seems CListViee uses ajax by default. Look at html generaited with target comtroller - check if some js code linked to pager links exists. Sorry for my english :)